# Taking a screenshot of the area under your application

Tags: c#, screenshot, desktop

I'm working on an application that requires the program to take a screenshot of the monitor, and lets the user interact with the resulting bitmap. I've written code (using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`) that will accomplish this task for any monitor that is hooked up. I'm working with two monitors, though, which allows me to have some interesting application open on one monitor, and my software on the other. In one monitor environments, all the screenshot code does is take a picture of my program (which is necessarily maximized on the screen).

Is there any way to take a screenshot of the area UNDER my application? This might be the desktop, but more likely will be whatever arrangement of windows is active if my application wasn't running. In theory, minimizing my application, taking a screenshot of what's shown, then un-minimizing my application would work, except I'm going to be taking these screenshots frequently and asynchronously while the user is interacting with my software, so it needs to be seamlessly done without the user knowing the application was minimized or interrupted.

My code for taking screenshots is below (pulled from some other code, so excuse the mess), in case there is reason to look over it.

```
public Bitmap getScreenshot()
    {
        Rectangle rc = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea; // the OTHER monitor
        Rectangle rcClient = this.ClientRectangle;

        Bitmap memoryImage = null;

        try
        {
            int borderSizeH = 0, borderSizeW = 0;

            memoryImage = new Bitmap(rc.Width - 2 * borderSizeW, rc.Height - 2 * borderSizeH, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            Size rc2 = new Size(rc.Width, rc.Height);
            using (Graphics memoryGrahics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage))
            {
                memoryGrahics.CopyFromScreen(rc.Location.X + borderSizeW, rc.Location.Y + borderSizeH, 0, 0, rc2, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Capture failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

       return memoryImage;
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if it would work better/faster, but maybe setting the visibility instead of min/max the window would work?

Comment: You are looking for X-Ray Specs.  Luckily it is easy to get one from Winforms.  Just set the Opacity property of your form to 99%.  It won't show up in the screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these solutions flicker the window. If the user starts a timer to take a screenshot often, the window constantly flickers, making the program impossible to work with. Otherwise these solutions would work for me.

I'm hoping for a solution that doesn't make it obvious the window state had to be changed if you take screenshots repeatedly.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?